# ZSH Environment variables

Tags: shell, zsh, environment-variables

What is the difference between these two lines:

```
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config"
export XINITRC="${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/x11/xinitrc"
```

And these two lines:

```
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config"
export XINITRC="${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/x11/xinitrc"
```

In other words, what is the difference in referencing the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` variable by itself like in the second example, versus using the variable like this: `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}`? Repeating the path seems redundant since we are already setting the value for the variable `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}` before we reference it in the `XINITRC` variable.

Answer (score 1):

See [`info zsh 'Parameter Expansion'`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion):

> `${NAME-WORD}`
> `${NAME:-WORD}`
> If NAME is set, or in the second form is non-null, then substitute
> its value; otherwise substitute WORD.  In the second form NAME may
> be omitted, in which case WORD is always substituted.

That's a feature inherited from the Bourne shell (from the late 70s) and present in all Bourne-like or POSIX shells (except for the last part about omitting *NAME* which is a `zsh`-specific extension).

So `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}` expands to the value of the `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` variable if non-empty or to `$HOME/.config` otherwise.

Given that `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` has been defined to something guaranteed to be non-empty above, it's redundant indeed.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your assistance!